# Usando formula em SQL

Tags: sql, count, union, fórmula

Olá, estou com uma dúvida e não acho exemplos para progredir, seguinte:

```
select  
    'disponivel' as TIPO  
    , COUNT(distinct dp.ds_nome) as qtd  
FROM  
    dm_pessoa_treino dp  
union ALL  
select  
    'em_uso' as TIPO  
    ,COUNT(distinct nm_cpf) as qtd  
FROM  
    ft_pessoa_treino fp  

Resultado:  
|tipo       |qtd |  
|disponivel |2845|  
|em_uso     |2848|

Proposição:
Quero poder exibir um resultado com a seguinte equação: N(disp.) * 100 / N(uso)  
usando como base os resultados de COUNT.
```

Answer (score 0):

Retirei o campos que você coloca como Tipo, separei os dois selects e fiz um select que ja faz a conta com o outro select.
No firebird ficaria assim:

```
select
    (
    (select
       COUNT(distinct dp.ds_nome) as qtd
    FROM  
        dm_pessoa_treino dp  ) *100)
     /
    (select
        COUNT(distinct nm_cpf) as qtd
    FROM  
        ft_pessoa_treino fp)
    )
from
    rdb$database
```

Answer (score 0):

Flavio, não sei qual banco de dados você está utilizando, mas segue uma sugestão para testes:

```
with CTE_Qtds as
(
  select  
    'disponivel' as TIPO  
    ,COUNT(distinct dp.ds_nome) as qtd  
  FROM dm_pessoa_treino dp  

  union ALL  

  select  
    'em_uso' as TIPO  
    ,COUNT(distinct nm_cpf) as qtd  
  FROM ft_pessoa_treino fp  
)

select * 
from CTE_Qtds

union all

select 
  'resultado', 
  100.0 * d.qtd / u.qtd
from CTE_Qtds as d
cross join CTE_Qtds as u
where 
  d.tipo = 'disponível' and 
  u.tipo = 'em_uso'
```

Espero que ajude